# Android, multiple spannable texts in textview color isn't changing

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I'm trying to apply color to different spannablestrings but when I append the strings to the textview only the first one is colored and the rest are ignored.

the variables orange and red are color ints

```
final ForegroundColorSpan orangeSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(orange);
final ForegroundColorSpan greySpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(grey);

String orignalName = post.getUser().getUsername();

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(orignalName+"'s");
        s.setSpan(orangeSpan, 0, orignalName.length(),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        postView.tvUsername.append(s);

        SpannableString endStr = new SpannableString(" post");
        endStr.setSpan(greySpan, 0,3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        postView.tvUsername.append(endStr);
```

Comment: Your code kinda works for me. I mean, color is applied to the second SpannableString, but your `int end` parameter is off by 2. Are you sure you just aren't seeing the change? (It appears the color is actually gray, going by your variable names.) Try changing it to a blatantly different color.

Comment: thats odd, I ended up just using html markup in the strings, way easier but feels a little hacky.